# Help with a recurrence with even and odd terms

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

I have the following recurrence that I've been pounding on:

$$
a(0)=1\\
a(1)=1\\
a(2)=2\\
a(2n)=a(n)+a(n+1)+n\ \ \ (\forall n>1)\\
a(2n+1)=a(n)+a(n-1)+1\ \ \ (\forall n\ge 1)
$$

I don't have much background in solving these things, so I've been googling around looking for different techniques. Unfortunately, I haven't been able to correctly apply them yet. So far I've tried:

- Characteristic equations
- Generating functions
- Plugging it into Wolfram Alpha
- Telescoping
- Observation

I'm sure that one or more of these is the way to go, but my biggest problem right now is figuring out how to deal with the idea that there are different equations for odd and even values of $n$. I'm not necessarily looking for a solution (though it would be gratefully accepted), but any nudges in the right direction would be much appreciated.

---

To follow up, it turned out that the speed problem described in my comment, below was related to the Decimal implementation in Python 2.7. Switching to Python 3.3 (and Java) made everything many orders of magnitude better.

Comment: Where did you get the recurrence in the first place?

Comment: I haven't got a solution, but it looks like it would be tricky (if a closed form exists), since most the standard techniques assume $a_n$ would be a function of $a_{n-1},a_{n-2},\ldots, a_{n-k}$ for some fixed $k$ - but having $a_{2n}$ depend on $a_n$ makes that not work, which is likely to stop a lot of otherwise good general techniques.

Comment: The recurrence is actually from a larger problem where the object is to find where in the series a particular value occurs. I have a working solution to that problem using a binary search, but it's not quite as fast as I'd like it to be since I have to calculate a(n) a bunch of times to get there.

Comment: @ScottHarris Could you perhaps demonstrate how you solved the larger problem? It might help solidify some nuances with the approach.

Comment: I also couldn't find it in OEIS :(

Comment: @ScottHarris did you solve this in the end?

Comment: @paranoid-android As I mentioned in my edit and comment, the full problem was to find where in the series a particular value occurs. I had coded up a binary search solution to that problem in Python 2.7 using the Decimal library, but it was extremely slow with all of the iterations of this series that were required. It turned out, though, that the main culprit for that was the Decimal library for Python 2.7. Once I switched to Java and its BigInteger library, it was significantly (10,000x+) faster. So, in summary, I never solved the topic of this question, but I did solve my problem.

Comment: @ScottHarris How did your binary search solution work if the values are not ordered, ie a(k) might be bigger than a(k+1).

Comment: @paranoid-android A couple of things helped with that. First, $n \leq a(n)$ in (almost) all cases, so that gives you an upper bound on your search area. Second, one thing I forgot to mention was that, since some values of $a(n)$ can be repeated, the goal was actually to find the last occurrence of the given value. Since $a(2n) > a(2n-1)$ (i.e. a solution for an even value of $n$ is larger than that for the odd value preceding it), I ended up doing the search twice sometimes. The first time was only over the odd values of $n$. If a solution was found, quit. Otherwise, repeat over even values.

Comment: @paranoid-android One more thing: I was saving values of $a(n)$ as I went along to help speed up the calculation. With the $2n$ factor, I only had to save $log(n)$ values -- that helped a LOT for large values ($> 10^{20}$) of $n$.

Comment: I just got this problem in Google Foobar. I ended up writing a very simple program running two binary searches using a memoized function that computes the recursion. I didn't run into any performance issues with this approach, even using Python 2.7.

Comment: @JacopoNotarstefano Weird. Did you use the Decimal library for it? I ended up running into precision problems for large values of $n$ without it.

Comment: @ScottHarris No, I just used the standard Python integer type.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1053112/finding-matrix-for-given-recurrence

Answer (score 6):

I have an almost closed form. It uses the functions $z_2(n)$, which is the number of zeros in the binary representation of $n$ (after the first non-zero digit, of course) and $Z_2(n)=\sum_{i=1}^n z_2(n)$. I am quite sure these can be calculated quickly, but I'll leave that to you.

---

**Section 1: A Closed Form For S(n).**

Running off of Michael Biro's answer, where they define $S(n)=a(n+2)-a(n)$ and calculate that $S(2n)=S(n)+1$ and $S(2n+1)=S(n-1)$, we can find a closed form for $S$ and then find a neat sum for it.

In particular, rewrite Michaels two properties as:
$$S(n)=S(2n+3)=S(2n)-1.$$
and consider that this measures the numbers of even numbers we pass through as we iterate the function $f(2n+3)=n$ and $f(2n)=n$. We also have the edge conditions
$$S(0)=1$$
$$S(1)=2$$
$$S(2)=5$$
Now, this relation is clearly dealing with something happening in binary - but even better than binary is to write $n$ in base $2$, leading with the digit $1$ or $3$ and otherwise using the digits $0$ and $3$ - meaning that the expansion of $2n$ is the expansion of $n$, with a $0$ appended, and the expansion of $2n+3$ is the expansion of $n$ with a $3$ appended. This means that the map $f$ just chops off the last digits of this representation! A table of such representations follows:
\begin{array}{ll}
n & n_2 \\
 1 & 1 \\
 2 & 10 \\
 3 & 3 \\
 4 & 100 \\
 5 & 13 \\
 6 & 30 \\
 7 & 103 \\
 8 & 1000 \\
 9 & 33 \\
 10 & 130 \\
 11 & 1003 \\
 12 & 300 \\
 13 & 133 \\
 14 & 1030 \\
 15 & 303 \\
 16 & 10000 \\
 17 & 1033 \\
\end{array}
What is notable is that if the pattern starts with "3", then it will iterate to $0$ under $f$ after some number of steps, meaning $S(n)$ would be the number of $0$s in the expansion (how many times the orbit of $n$ under $f$ passed through even numbers), plus $S(0)=1$. If the pattern starts with "10", then $n$ first passes through $2$ under $f$, so $S(n)$ would be the number of zeros in the expansion (excluding the first one used in the pattern "10") plus $S(2)=5$. If the pattern starts with "13", then $n$ passes through $1$ under $f$ and so $S(n)$ equals the number of zeros in the pattern, plus $S(1)=2$.

This looks kind of intimidating to start with, but it's actually not too bad. Notice that if we chop off the most significant digit of our representation, the resulting representation is divisible by $3$, since it only uses the digits $0$ and $3$ and, moreover, if we divide that by $3$ and write it in normal binary, it's the same as if we replaced every $3$ by a $1$. Therefore, if we let $z_2(n)$ be the number of zeros in the normal binary representation of $n$, then we can interpret the above as follows, letting $2^b$ be the place value of the $1$ in our representation of $n$ if it exists (which must happen if $3$ doesn't divide $n$):
$$S(n)=\begin{cases}z_2\left(\frac{n}3\right)+1&&\text{if }n\equiv 0\pmod 3 \\ z_2\left(\frac{n+2\cdot 2^b}3\right)+2&&\text{if }5\cdot 2^{b-1} \leq n  \\ z_2\left(\frac{n+2\cdot 2^b}3\right)+4&&\text{if }n < 5\cdot 2^{b-1}\end{cases}$$
where we add $2\cdot 2^b$ to $n$ to convert the first digit from a $1$ to a $3$ and the condition that $5\cdot 2^{b-1}\leq n$ is equivalent to the expansion of $n$ beginning with "13". We require knowing $b$ to calculate the above, but noticing that we must have that
$$n=2^b+3\cdot k$$
for some $0\leq k \leq 2^b-1$, implying $2^b\leq n \leq 4\cdot 2^b - 3$, it is obvious that $b$ must either be $\lfloor\log_2(n)\rfloor$ or $\lfloor\log_2(n)\rfloor-1$ and that $n-2^b$ is divisible by $3$. So, we could write:
$$b=\begin{cases}\lfloor\log_2(n)\rfloor && \text{if }2^{\lfloor\log_2(n)\rfloor}\equiv n\pmod 3\\\lfloor\log_2(n)\rfloor-1 && \text{if }2^{\lfloor\log_2(n)\rfloor-1}\equiv n\pmod 3\end{cases}.$$

We could quickly write the expansion of some large integer using this information. Say we wanted to know the representation of $124315$ which is $1$ mod $3$ and is between $2^{16}$ and $2^{17}-1$ so $b'=16$. We note that $124315-2^{16}$ is divisible by $3$, so we know our expansion will have a $1$ in the $2^{16}$ position followed by the binary representation of $\frac{124315-2^{16}}3=1110010110011011_2$ with $1$'s replaced by $3$'s. This gives:
$$124315=13330030330033033_2$$

---

**Section 2: A Closed Form For $a(n)$**

We are going to have to split into cases for this, which is annoying. In particular, from the definition of $S$, we obviously have:
$$a(2n)=1+\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}S(2i)$$
$$a(2n+1)=1+\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}S(2i+1)$$
Let's start with the even case because it works out more nicely. In particular, let's rewrite $S(2i)=S(i)+1$ and get:
$$a(2n)=1+\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}S(i)+1$$
which means that we are taking the sum of $S$ over all numbers less than $n$. To do this, we just need to find all representations in our system giving a number less than $n$. For convenience, we'll define $[n]$ to be the greatest integer strictly less than $n$ (so $[5]=4$ for instance). Next, we get to four cases

1. First, let's list every representation starting with "3". This is equivalent to listing all binary representations less than $\frac{n}3$. So, since $S(3n)=z_2(n)+1$, if we define $$Z_2(n)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}z_2(i)$$ then the contribution of these $2\left[\frac{n}3\right]$ terms to the sum is: $$Z_2\left(\left[\frac{n}3\right]\right)+2\left[\frac{n}3\right]$$
2. Next, consider representations starting with "13". Choose $b_1$ to be such that $5\cdot 2^{b_1-1}\leq n\leq 4\cdot 2^{b_1}-3$, which would be the place value of the $1$ in the largest such representation less than or equal to $n$. Notice that if the $1$ is in a lower place value, but the string still began "13", then the representation would still be lesser than $n$, since it would be bounded above by $2\cdot 2^{b_1}< 5\cdot 2^{b_1-1} \leq n$. Therefore, if we take an binary number less than $\frac{n-2^{b_1}}{3}$, converted all the 1s to 3s and prepended a "1", we would get a valid representation starting with "3". The contribution of these terms to the sum would be:
   $$Z_2\left(\left[\frac{n-2^{b_1}}3\right]\right)+3\left[\frac{n-2^{b_1}}3\right]$$
   It is possible that no suitable $b_1$ exists, in which case choose $b_1$ to be the largest value such that $4\cdot 2^{b_1}-3<n$, meaning that any number with the $1$ in the place with value $2^{b_1}$ works, giving a contribution of $2^{b_1-1}-1$ terms as:
   $$Z_2\left(2^{b_1-1}-1\right)+3\cdot 2^{b_1-1}-3$$
3. Now, consider representations starting with "100". Choose $b_2$ to be such that $$2^{b_2}\leq n \leq 7\cdot 2^{b_2-2}-3.$$ The contribution of these terms will be
   $$Z_2\left(\left[\frac{n-2^{b_2-1}}3\right]\right)+7\left[\frac{n-2^{b_2-1}}3\right]$$
   or, if no such $b_2$ exists, letting $b_2$ instead be the greatest value such that $2^{b_2}\leq n$, giving a contribution of:
   $$Z_2\left(2^{b_2-2}-1\right)+7\cdot 2^{b_2-2}-7$$
4. Finally, we consider representation starting with "103". Choose $b_3$ to be such that $7\cdot 2^{b_3-2}\leq n \leq 5\cdot 2^{b_3-1}-3$. The contribution of thse terms will be
   $$Z_2\left(\left[\frac{n-2^{b_3}}3\right]\right)+6\left[\frac{n-2^{b_3}}3\right]$$ 
   and if no such $b_3$ exists, choose the largest such that $7\cdot 2^{b_3-2}<n$. Then, the contribution will be:
   $$Z_2\left(2^{b_3-2}-1\right)+6\cdot 2^{b_3-2}-1.$$
5. We have not yet counted the strings "10", and "1". They contribute $9$ to the sum (assuming $n>2$).

Now, if you just sum up all those contributions, making the big assumption that I didn't make a single computation error in this entire post, you should get $a(2n)$. It's not really worth compiling those into a single equation, since there are essentially $8$ cases. I'll leave the odd cases to you, but it should proceed analogously. You just need to compute $Z_2(n)$ quickly, but I think this is probably easy enough since it has the identity:
$$Z_2(2^{k}-1)=k\cdot (2^{k-1}-1)$$
and should have nice identities for $Z_2(2^{k_1}+2^{k_2}-1)$ and so on as we specify more digits. (There's still substantial computation to do here, but it should take *linear* time in the number of digits, rather than quadratic time, as the naive algorithm would take)

Answer (score 4):

This isn't a full answer, but might make a solution more tractable.

Define $S(n) = a(n+2) - a(n)$. (FYI I wasn't able to find $S(n)$ sequence in OEIS either)

Then, we get that

$S(2n) = a(2n+2) - a(2n) = a(n+2) + a(n+1) + (n+1) - a(n+1) - a(n) - n = a(n+2) - a(n)  + 1 = S(n) + 1$

and

$S(2n+1) = a(2n+3) - a(2n+1) = a(n+1) + a(n) + 1 - a(n) - a(n-1) - 1 = a(n+1) - a(n-1) = S(n-1)$

So the recurrence for $S(2n) = S(n) + 1$ and $S(2n+1) = S(n-1)$. This still has a parity difference in the recursion, but is a bit simpler.

I spent a little while trying to work out a Josephus problem type solution for $S(n)$, with only partial results (i.e. if $n = 2^k + 3(2^j-1)$ with $0 \leq j < k$ and $2 \leq k$, then $S(n) = k - j + 4$). At the very least that shows that the differences between $a(n+2)$ and $a(n)$ vary between small constant values and up values around $\log n$.

Comment: This looks like it simplifies it a bit. I'm not sure if this $S(n)$ recursion is helpful or just a rewriting of the original recursion. Either way, nice work. +1

Comment: If you "follow" the recursion with a map $f$ taking $2n+1\mapsto n-1$ and $2n\mapsto n$ (which is kind of like the Collatz map), then $S$ measures how many even numbers you pass through before reaching $1$.

Comment: Observation: $S(n)$ appears to be related to the number of pairs $11$ and characters $0$ in the binary representation of $n$.

Comment: @anorton can you elaborate on that at all? How did you determine that?

Comment: @paranoid-android Since the recurrence involves dividing by two a lot, I did my scratch work in binary.  My observation above is just something I noticed after working a couple of cases.  I'll try to formalize it in the morning; it's nearly 2am here, and I need some sleep.  :)

Comment: I've been playing with log base 2, so I think we're heading in a similar direction.

Answer (score 0):

Just to save others computing the sequence, here is a program for the first $m$ terms:

```
package main
import "fmt"
const m = 100
func main() {
    a := [m]int{1, 1, 2}
    for i := 3; i < m; i++ {
        if i % 2 == 1 {
            h := (i - 1)/2
            a[i] = a[h] + a[h-1] + 1
        } else {
            h := i/2
            a[i] = a[h] + a[h+1] + h
        }
    }
    fmt.Println(a)
}
```

For $m=100$ we get

> 1 1 2 3 7 4 13 6 15 11 22 12 25 18 28 20 34 22 42 27 44 34 48 35 55 38 59 44 62 47 69 49 72 55 81 57 87 65 90 70 98 72 103 79 105 83 113 84 117 91 122 94 129 98 133 104 137 107 145 110 148 117 152 119 159 122 169 128 172 137 179 139 188 145 192 153 198 156 207 161 210 169 216 171 224 176 227 183 232 185 241 189 243 197 248 198 256 202 262 209

This does not turn up on the integer sequences website.

Comment: This isn't really an answer, but at least you put it as "community wiki." The reason I generally don't like answers that aren't answers is that it means that the question is now removed from the "unanswered" pile and less people will see it. In reality, the question is still not answered, and more people should see it.

Answer (score -4):

If you consider each element and $a_0$, $a_1$, $a_2$,... You eventually see $a_2$ is just y(0)$a_{0}$.  And $a_3$ is just y(1)$a_{1}$.  $a_4$ = y(2)*y(0)$a_0$. $a_5$ = y(3)*y(1)$a_1$. Assuming you get a different answer for $a_0$ and $a_1$.  You will always get different results for even and odd inputs.

Comment: This is not at all helpful.  OP seems to understand how to calculate individual terms, but seeks a general formula. It is not in general true that $a_n=a_{n-2}+2$ which seems to be what you are implying.

Comment: I meant a_2 equals a_{0+2}.  Go look up power series solution then get back to me.

Comment: @JamilSantos $a_2 = a_{0+2}$ is simply a consequence of $2 = 0+2$. How exactly is this helpful?

Comment: But $a_n$ in this case is *not* just a formula in terms of $a_{n-2}$, and cannot be written that way.

Comment: By definition a reccurence formula equates $a_n$ to $a_{n−x}$. Say n=2 and x=2. If the recurrence formula is $a_{n+2}$ = y(n)$a_n$. $a_2$ will equal y(0)$a_0$. $a_3$ will equal y(1)$a_1$. $a_4$ will equal y(2)$a_2$=y(2)*y(0)$a_0$, $a_5$ equals y(3)$a_3$=y(3)*y(1)$a_1$. Assuming n is positive , it must be greater than 1, otherwise it is just an equation and not a recurrence. If each a_n was independent it would be a simple function and not a recurrence formula.