# How can I convert a recursive equation to a non-recursion one?

Tags: linear-algebra, algorithms, recurrence-relations, recursive-algorithms, recursion

While I am aware of several other similar question which have been asked in the past, my mathematical education only extends through calculus, making them beyond my comprehension, and I believe this specific problem is harder because of the (2n) component.  I would like to convert the below function into a non recursive one (to reduce its compute time), and would greatly appreciate any explanation for how to do so, especially if they don't require advanced knowledge, or the solution.  Thanks!

> $$\begin{align}
>  R(0) &= 1   \\
>  R(1) &= 1   \\
>  R(2) &= 2   \\
>  R(2n) &= R(n) + R(n + 1) + n \quad\quad (\text{for } n > 1)  \\
>  R(2n + 1) &= R(n - 1) + R(n) + 1 \quad\quad (\text{for } n \ge 1)  \\
> \end{align}$$

(n is a whole number)

Edit: Here is a list of the first 40 elements.
[1,1,2,3,7,4,13,6,15,11,22,12,25,18,28,20,34,22,42,27,44,34,48,35,55,38,59,44,62,47,69,49,72,55,81,57,87,65,90,70]

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: yes, my mistake. It seems to be quite complicated. Also OEIS gives no match.

Comment: Have you seen this?  http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1053112/97045

Comment: @DanielV Thanks, unfortunately I have no idea what is going on in that explanation and it will take a bit of reading to understand it.

Comment: @JohnDrake Indeed, that is why I didn't flag this as duplicate, since the given answer is fairly hard to understand (it is a hard problem to begin with) that asking for further  help or generalization might be appreciated (my opinion not necessarily site policy).

Comment: There's [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1060154/help-with-a-recurrence-with-even-and-odd-terms/) too. My solution there is pretty elementary.

Comment: @Meelo Thanks! The object here is purely computational speed, and I don't really care how it's achieved.  If you were wondering this problem has appeared four times in the last month as a result of an invitational set of problems presented by a tech company, and the programmers who attempt them are being baffled by the maths in this one.