# Solution to recurrence relation: $f(x) = f(x-2)+f(x/2)$ for even $x$, $f(x)=f(x-1)$ for odd $x$.

Tags: recurrence-relations

I need to find a solution for, or at least a way to compute efficiently, the following recurrence equation:

$$f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
f(x-2)+f(x/2),  & \text{if $x$ is even} \\
f(x-1), & \text{if $x$ is odd.}
\end{cases}$$

Also, $f(0)=f(1)=1$.

I looked back at my notes from college years, none of the ones we studied look similar to this form, none of them has anything like $x/2$ in indexes.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Somewhat reminds me of this kind of recursion: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1053112/finding-matrix-for-given-recurrence

Comment: If you're generating these terms in sequence then a simple memoized recursive function is reasonably efficient. FWIW, I can generate the first 250,000 terms in Python on a 2GHz machine in under 1.5 seconds.

Comment: You still have your college notes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that we can write this as

$$f(n) = 
\begin{cases}
f(n-1)+f(n/2),  & \text{if $n$ is even} \\
f(n-1), & \text{if $n$ is odd.}
\end{cases}$$

Now, consider the function $F(x)=\sum_{n\ge0}f(n)x^n$, and split its terms according to the parity of $n$:

$$F(x)=\sum_{n\ge0}f(n)x^n=\sum_{n \text{ even}}f(n)x^n+\sum_{n \text{ odd}}f(n)x^n$$

$$=\sum_{n \text{ even}}[f(n-1)+f(n/2)]x^n+\sum_{n \text{ odd}}f(n-1)x^n$$

$$=\sum_{n\ge0}f(n-1)x^n+\sum_{n\ge0}f(n)x^{2n}=xF(x)+F(x^2)$$

$$\implies (1-x)F(x)=F(x^2) \implies F(x)=\frac{F(x^{2^{n+1}})}{(1-x)(1-x^2)(1-x^4)...(1-x^{2^n})} $$

Using that $F(0)=1$, and with a little care about convergence, we can see that

$$F(x)=\prod_{n\ge 0}\frac{1}{1-x^{2^n}}$$

and this matches up nicely with @Giovanni Resta's claim that this is the number of partitions of $n$ into powers of $2$.

Answer (score 2):

Generating the first terms and looking up them in the [OEIS](https://oeis.org/) it turns out this sequence is [A018819](https://oeis.org/A018819), i.e.,        *Binary partition function: number of partitions of n into powers of 2*.

In the OEIS you will find several biblio refs about this sequence and some formulas and connections with other combinatorial problems.

However, all the explicit formulas reported seems to express $a(n)$ in terms of previous values.